# Can't use Nivo tooltip or crosshair draggability on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive, react-vis, nivo-react

I'm trying to create a line chart that uses crosshairs and tooltip using Nivo. I was able to get everything working great on desktop, but on mobile, when I try to drag across the graph with my finger, nothing happens. The only time the crosshair and tooltip comes up is when I tap.

This draggable functionality was working with react-vis, but I needed to move away from that for various reasons.

Any recommendations or help?

Comment: The same issues to me. so I replaced the chart with an ApexChart module to solve the issue. here is the link. https://apexcharts.com